# How to select from a table in a different database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have many database instances say for e.g `EWB1,EWB2,EWB3` and so on..if suppose I am in `EWB1` and I want to access a particular table's column from other nstances (in this case say `EWB2,EWB3` and so on).. I am doing something like this

```
declare @name varchar(10);
DECLARE cur3 CURSOR FOR select EnterpriseDBInstance from [EWB_DAL].[dbo].[Enterprise] where EnterpriseDBInstance <>  CONVERT(varchar(10),DB_NAME());
OPEN cur3;
Fetch next from cur3 into @name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
declare @test varchar(10);
set @test = (select @name);     
select ChapterName from [@test].[dbo].[FormData] -- This line is giving error
                                                 -- unable to find @test....
Fetch next from cur3 into @name;
END
close cur3; 
deallocate cur3;
```

But I could see `EWB2,EWB3...` in @test..

Comment: What database are you using? Each vendor has a different way of supporting such functionality (if at all). What is "SQL 2008"? Do you mean SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use database names dynamically (i.e using variables), in the same way that you can't use table or column names in such a manner.

The query you have is trying to find a database named `@test`.

You need to look at using dynamic SQL for such work, or rethink your approach. I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

use qoutename like qoutename(ur DB variable name) this works...